# Why this while loop is only running once in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
package search
import java.util.*
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

    println("Enter the number of people: ")
    val datasetSize = scanner.nextInt()

    println("Enter all people: ")
    val dataset = Array<String>(datasetSize){readLine()!!}
    println("===Menu===")
    println("1. Find a person")
    println("2. Print all people")
    println("0. Exit")
    var choice = scanner.nextInt()
    while(true){
        when(choice) {
            1 -> find(datasetSize,dataset)
            2 -> listp(datasetSize,dataset)
            0 -> exitProcess(-1)
            else -> println("Incorrect option! Try again.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put these things inside while loop to display it in the console for multiple times

```
println("===Menu===")
println("1. Find a person") 
println("2. Print all people") 
println("0. Exit") 
var choice = scanner.nextInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the menu to run multiple times, so you have to move the `while` to include the menu logic.
fun main() {
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

```
println("Enter the number of people: ")
val datasetSize = scanner.nextInt()

println("Enter all people: ")
val dataset = Array<String>(datasetSize){readLine()!!}
while(true){
    println("===Menu===")
    println("1. Find a person")
    println("2. Print all people")
    println("0. Exit")
    var choice = scanner.nextInt()
    when(choice) {
        1 -> find(datasetSize,dataset)
        2 -> listp(datasetSize,dataset)
        0 -> exitProcess(-1)
        else -> println("Incorrect option! Try again.")
    }
}
```

}